# Namedtuple not defined on windows interpreter

Tags: python, tuples, traceback, namedtuple

I'm trying to follow the usage example of `namedtuple( )` from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), but I keep getting `namedtuple is not defined`.

[image: Traceback]

Comment: You haven't imported it yet. `from collections import namedtuple`

Comment: Oh yeah I'm so stupid. Thank you!

Comment: lol don't worry. Those things happen a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `import collections` up top, then you can do `collections.namedtuple`

You can also do `from collections import namedtuple` and it should work like in the docs

Comment: Thank you so much! I was being stupid.